# How to insert bulk data into using postgres and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to insert multiple rows into Postgres through node.js. Below is an example of the data:

```
{
  "student_id": 18,
  "marks_info": [
    {  
      "subject": "math",
      "marks": 99,
      "status": "P"
    },
    {  
      "subject": "social",
      "marks": 76,
      "status": "p"
    },
    {  
      "subject": "science",
      "marks": 56,
      "status": "p"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following query in node.js:

```js
const student_data = req.body
const data = student_data.marks_info;

const values = data.reduce((mk, i) => [...mk, Object.values(i)], []);
eg :
[ ['math' ,99,'p' ], ['social',76,'p' ],['science',56,'p'] ]
const query = "INSERT INTO marks(subject, marks, status) VALUES ($1,$2,$3)";
pool.query(query, [values], (err, results) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error:", err);
  }
  console.log("Results:", results);
});
```

But it throws an error: `invalid input syntax for type integer:.

I have seen this solution from other resources, but I'm not able to get a response. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Postgres does not use `?` but `$1` for parameters: https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query